# How do I make a JMS topic variable in Grails?

Tags: grails, jms, jms-topic

I have recently run into a problem with trying to make the topic of my JMS @Subscriber a variable based upon environment. Currently, I have in my config.groovy:

```
environments {
    development {
        jms.foo.msg = "my.jms.topic.dev.1_0"
    }
    test {
        jms.foo.msg = "my.jms.topic.tst.1_0"
    }
    production {
        jms.foo.msg = "my.jms.topic.prd.1_0"
    }
}
```

And in my service, where I have my @Subscriber, I have this:

```
@Subscriber(
            topic = grailsApplication.config.jms.foo.msg,
            container = 'matter',
            adapter = 'durable'
)
```

The error that I am getting is:
    "Expected 'grailsApplication.config.jms.foo.msg' to be an inline constant."

I have tried many variations of getting the config value here. All I am looking for is how to subscribe to the proper topic while on a specific environment. Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Holders (since Grails v2.0):

`import grails.util.Holders`

And then use:

`@Subscriber(
            topic = Holders.getConfig().jms.foo.msg,
            container = 'matter',
            adapter = 'durable'
)`

Comment: I had tried this and was getting the same issue. What I have ended up doing for the mean time is this:

    static exposes = ["jms"]
    static destination = Holders.config.jms.destinations.foo.msg
    static isTopic = true
    static container = 'matter'
    static adapter = 'durable'

    def onMessage(msg) {...some code}
This allowed for the use of config values, where as the annotation does not seem to.